# How to ensure React updates are in sequence?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a multi-select dropdown and want to hide the options as soon as user picks one option, but I am unable to hide the dropdown after `selectedCategoriesData` state is updates since the `setShowCategories(false);` update stops the `selectedCategoriesData` state from updating.

How to ensure that `selectedCategoriesData` state is updated first and then `setShowCategories`.

*Please read the comment for my problem*

Here are the files:

**Filter.jsx**:

```
import classes from "./Filter.module.css";

const Filter = ({ categories }) => {
  const [selectedCategoriesData, setSelectedCategoriesData] = useState([]);
  const [showCategories, setShowCategories] = useState(false);
  const handleCategoryInput = (e) => {};

  const handleCategorySelect = (categoryChosen) => {
    setSelectedCategoriesData([...selectedCategoriesData, categoryChosen]);
    // setShowCategories(false);   <---- This is causing not to update the selectedCategoriesData state, why ? I also want to hide the dropdown of options, so I need to set setShowCategories to false AFTER the selectedCategoriesData state is updated.
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.filter_container}>
      <div className="category_filter">
        <label htmlFor="ctgry">Category</label>
        <input
          className={classes.category_select}
          onChange={handleCategoryInput}
          onFocus={() => setShowCategories(true)}
          onBlur={() => setShowCategories(false)}
        ></input>
        {showCategories && (
          <ul className={classes.categories_data}>
            {categories.map((category, index) => (
              <li tabIndex={0} key={index} onClick={() => handleCategorySelect(category)}>
                <span>{category}</span>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Filter;
```

**Filter.module.css** :

```
.filter_container {
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.filter_container label {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.category_select {
  min-width: 20rem;
  border: 1px solid #494949;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  display: block;
}

.categories_data {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-top: none;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  max-height: 20rem;
  width: 20rem;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.categories_data:hover {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.categories_data li span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.65rem 0.8rem;
}

.categories_data li:hover {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.categories_data::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 1rem; /* width of the entire scrollbar */
}

.categories_data::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent; /* color of the tracking area */
}

.categories_data::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #4b4b4b; /* color of the scroll thumb */
  border-radius: 20px; /* roundness of the scroll thumb */
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  /* creates padding around scroll thumb */
}
```

categories props is array of `['category-1', 'category-2', 'category-3', 'category-4', 'category-5', 'category-6']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading your issue carefully and running your code, I realize that the issue is caused due to `onBlur={() => setShowCategories(false)}` functionality in your input statement. This is triggering `setShowCategories(false)` before updating your `SelectedCategoriesData` state.

To get the functionality of closing the dropdown while clicking outside the input component, you can use `ref` and `eventlistener` instead of `onBlur`. Here is the code for this implementation:

```js
const Filter = ({ categories }) => {
  const [selectedCategoriesData, setSelectedCategoriesData] = useState([]);
  const [showCategories, setShowCategories] = useState(false);
  const handleCategoryInput = (e) => {};

  const handleCategorySelect = (categoryChosen) => {
    console.log(categoryChosen);

    setSelectedCategoriesData([...selectedCategoriesData, categoryChosen]);
    setShowCategories(false); //<---- This is causing not to update the selectedCategoriesData state, why ? I also want to hide the dropdown of options, so I need to set setShowCategories to false AFTER the selectedCategoriesData state is updated.
  };

  // This will reference to the div surrounding your input components
  const ref = useRef();

  // Here we listen for mousdown event and if its outside our ref component we will make dropdown open false
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleClickOutside = (event) => {
      if (!ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
        setShowCategories(false);
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
  }, [ref]);

  return (
    <div className="filter_container">
      <div className="category_filter">
        <label htmlFor="ctgry">Category</label>
        <h4>selectedCategoriesData: {selectedCategoriesData}</h4>
        {showCategories ? <h1>True</h1> : <h1>False</h1>}
        {/* Input Component Start */}
        <div ref={ref}>
          <input
            className="category_select"
            onChange={handleCategoryInput}
            onFocus={() => setShowCategories(true)}
          ></input>
          {showCategories && (
            <ul className="categories_data">
              {categories.map((category, index) => (
                <li
                  tabIndex={0}
                  key={index}
                  onClick={() => handleCategorySelect(category)}
                >
                  <span>{category}</span>
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          )}
          </div>
          {/* Input Component End */}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Filter;
```

I hope this answer is helpful to you. Here is the sandbox link:
[Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-mountain-zp4j0d)